# times iterating does not work

Tags: ruby

I am trying to iterate `times` with a variable. Why does the variable `a` not count up?

```
a=0
pre="a"
until a > 10 do
 a.times print pre
 a +=1
end
```

Comment: Your question is misleading. Your code not only not counts up. It does not even run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be `a.times { print pre }`

Answer (score -1):

It's a little hard to tell from the code, but is the idea that the prepended text (`pre`) gets printed incrementally more times after each loop? E.g like:

```
a
aa
aaa
# etc...
```

You can achieve that with:

```
10.times do |i|
  i.times print pre
end
```